# Vaadin Component Factory Popup TypeError: Cannot read property 'popupOverlay' of undefined

Tags: javascript, error-handling, typeerror, vaadin

When using the VCF Popup Component (Vaadin 18, Popup v2.2.3) it throws a client side error trying to display it within a grid. I copied the "basic" example directly from the demo and just placed it into a grid component column, and as soon as the page renders I see a Javascript error notification. The popup actually displays fine, and there are no errors on the server side. Error and stack trace are below.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'popupOverlay' of undefined
```

The JS stack is

```
FlowClient.js?2d7e:188 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'popupOverlay' of undefined
at HTMLElement.eval (eval at Ut (FlowClient.js?2d7e:1), <anonymous>:3:29)
at Object.eval (eval at Ut (FlowClient.js?2d7e:1), <anonymous>:3:125)
at Ut (FlowClient.js?2d7e:1016)
at Tt (FlowClient.js?2d7e:970)
at Rt (FlowClient.js?2d7e:582)
at xr (FlowClient.js?2d7e:508)
at Vr.Wr [as db] (FlowClient.js?2d7e:1025)
at tB (FlowClient.js?2d7e:941)
at zr (FlowClient.js?2d7e:1020)
at Pr.Qr [as F] (FlowClient.js?2d7e:1025)
at pk (FlowClient.js?2d7e:427)
at rr (FlowClient.js?2d7e:1022)
at sr (FlowClient.js?2d7e:1002)
at lp.rp [as sb] (FlowClient.js?2d7e:1025)
at Object.eval (FlowClient.js?2d7e:991)
at sb (FlowClient.js?2d7e:435)
at vb (FlowClient.js?2d7e:888)
at Object.eval [as onMessage] (FlowClient.js?2d7e:612)
at _f (vaadinPush.js?v=5.0.2:2765)
at _invokeFunction (vaadinPush.js?v=5.0.2:2754)
at _invokeCallback (vaadinPush.js?v=5.0.2:2884)
at WebSocket._websocket.onmessage (vaadinPush.js?v=5.0.2:1457)
```

Is there any way to prevent, or at the very lease, hide this exception from the user?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is an issue in the component.

I've opened a ticket with the steps to reproduce: https://github.com/vaadin-component-factory/popup/issues/6

There isn't a workaround, so you need to wait for a new version.

Comment: There is a new version 2.2.4 of the component: https://vaadin.com/directory/component/popup
Can you update the version and try it ?